# Are there any PS3 Trophies for Soul Calibur IV?

Tags: achievements, ps3, soul-calibur-4

I saw that there are PS3 trophies for Soul Calibur V, but I would like to know if there are any for IV, and if so, what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not trophies, but there are unlockable honors. They're kind of like trophies, but they won't show up on your PS3 profile.

> - 10,000 Strikes of Proof - Land 10,000 attacks
> - Chosen by History - Create a Custom Character
> - Death on the Battlefield - Perform 100 Critical Finishes
> - Distance will not Betray - Reach over 10,000 meters in total movement distance in battle
> - Divine Punishment - K.O. with an Unblockable Attack
> - Encounter with the Unknown - Fight against Darth Vader (vs. mode doesn't count)
> - Endure 1,000 - Guard 1,000 times against attacks
> - Engraved into History - Fight 100 times (Online)
> - Equal Skill and Power - Use all skill points and set up 4 skills
> - First Step as an Artist - Customize a regular character
> - Gathering of the Best - Complete Chain Of Souls
> - Gladiator - Win consecutive Ranked Matches (Online)
> - Hero King - Level up to 20 (Online)
> - Hero on the Battlefield - Clear Arcade Mode with over 450,000 points
> - Iron Hammer - Land an attack on a taunting opponent
> - Legendary Hidden Treasures - Acquire over 30 treasures in Tower Of Lost Souls
> - Like a Flowing Stream - Perform 200 Impacts
> - Looter of the Battlefield - Collect all accessories
> - Lost in the Moment - Perform 20 Just Impacts
> - Mad Destroyer - Perform 100 Soul Crushes
> - Mystery of the Swords - Clear Story Mode on difficulty: Hard
> - Never Ending Advance - Descend 20 floors in Tower Of Lost Souls
> - Numeric God - The last two numbers of total play time and remaining time in a victorious battle are the same
> - Observer of Souls - Collect all illustrations in Art Gallery
> - Phoenix - Win with all equipment destroyed
> - Pursuer of the Secret - Clear Story Mode on difficulty: Normal
> - Quick Strike - Perform 5 First Attacks in a row in Arcade
> - Repel All Blades - Win 30 times with a perfect
> - Return to the Galaxy - Clear Story Mode with Darth Vader
> - Reversal Wizard - Win 20 times with low HP
> - Scorpion's Sting - Win a battle with Critical Finish
> - Sharpened Teeth - Maximize a style's level
> - Smasher - Destory all of the opponent's equipment
> - Start of a New Era - Welcome to the new world of Soul Calibur (Automatically awarded for playing)
> - Swift Strike - Perform 100 First Attacks
> - Sword Hunter - Collect all weapons for 5 characters.
> - The Controller - Get Soul Calibur (Final Form)
> - Tower of Gold - All is shrouded in mystery. (Collect 1,000,000 gold)
> - Tower's New Guardian - Clear all upper floors of Tower Of Lost Souls
> - Transcend History and the World - Acquire all weapons and equipment
> - Two Cannot Exist Together - Exhaust each other's power
> - Unknown Swordsman - Win 10 times (Online)
> - Violent Storm - Perform 50 Wall Hits
> - Wandering Assassin - K.O. opponent with over 20 types of weapons
> - Wandering Weapon Merchant - Collect 350 pieces of equipment
> - War Veteran - Clear Arcade Mode
> - Water Moon - Perform 30 grapple breaks
> - Wild Run to Tragedy - Get Soul Edge (Final Form)
> - World Class Fighter - Fight against 20 different fighting styles (Online)
> - World Traveler - Fight on all stages (Online)

Comment: List found on http://www.gamegrep.com/guides/13837-soul_calibur_iv_unlockable_honors_list/

Comment: why was this voted down? It is a good question on-topic.

Comment: and thanks for the help. I tried google but I guess I didn't search the right keywords. I voted you up. Even though I already knew the achievements in-game, at least now I know that there are not any PS3 Trophies.